# Finding mean of 3 numbers in c and avoid overflow. What's wrong with the code?

Tags: c

I want to find a mean of 3 numbers. The code works when all numbers are positive, but not when they're negative. What can I change?

```
int mean3(int a, int b, int c) {
    if ((a < 0) || (b < 0) || (c < 0)) {
        if ((a == b) && (b == c)) {
            return a;
        } else if (((a%3!=0) && (b%3!=0)) || ((a%3!=0) && (c%3!=0)) || ((b%3!=0) && (c%3!=0))) {
            return (a/3)+(b/3)+(c/3);
        } else {
            return (a/3)+(b/3)+(c/3)-1;
        }
    } else {
        if ((a == b) && (b == c)) {
            return a;
        } else if (((a%3!=0) && (b%3!=0)) || ((a%3!=0) && (c%3!=0)) || ((b%3!=0) && (c%3!=0))) {
            return (a/3)+(b/3)+(c/3)+1;
        } else {
            return (a/3)+(b/3)+(c/3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the `if ((a < 0) || (b < 0) || (c < 0)) {` test.

Comment: Finding the mean of three numbers is just (a+b+c)/3. I dont understand why your making it so complicated. Unless I dont understand what your trying to do.

Comment: @JackVanier: Arithmetic mean or geometric mean?

Comment: `(a/3)+(b/3)+(c/3)` is integer division and tosses away 3 remainders.  You may want `(a+b+c)/3` and only lose remainder.  Are you concerned about overflow?

Comment: I wonder if this code could be more complex. Using recursion would do, maybe.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It could always use floating-point.

Comment: "the code works when all numbers are positive, but not when they're negative." is better explained by posting an example including input, output and expected output.  So far it is unclear why `int mean3(int a, int b, int c) { return (a+b+c)/3; }` is not sufficient.  A more complicated `int mean3(int a, int b, int c) { return a/3 + b/3 + c/3 + (a%3 +b%3+c%3)/3; }` can handle overflow concerns.

Comment: if `if ((a < 0) || (b < 0) || (c < 0))` is meant to test that _all_ numbers are negative, you have a logic problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to prevent overflow, which is why i didn't do (a+b+c)/3.

Comment: @San why didn't you explain that in your question? without that info, your code is ridiculous. You should pre-compute the modulos to avoid doing them all over your code.

Comment: @San: If you want to avoid overflow, why don't you just do something like `return a/3+b/3+c/3+(a%3+b%3+c%3)/3;`?

Comment: As mentioned above, you are not comparing like with like. Only one number has to be negative to execute the first half of the code, but they are all positive in the second part. From the similarity I presume you think they are *all* negative in the first part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent `int` overflow, use `(a%3 +b%3+c%3)/3` to handle the division of the remainders. [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612829/finding-mean-of-3-numbers-in-c-whats-wrong-with-the-code/42612968#comment72354923_42612829)  [@Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612829/finding-mean-of-3-numbers-in-c-whats-wrong-with-the-code/42612968#comment72354877_42612829)

```
int mean3pf(int a, int b, int c) { 
  return a/3 + b/3 + c/3 + (a%3 +b%3+c%3)/3;
}
```

Comment: honest question: how does that behave with negative numbers?

Comment: Didn't think about that! Thanks!!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Code handle pos/neg numbers similarly, no special handling need for one or the other.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Depends of your C-standard. Since C99 (AFAIK), integer division is specified to work like this: C99 draft standard n1256: `6.5.5 Multiplicative operators 6 [...] If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression
(a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a.`. Before, there were multiple permissible ways for an implementation to implement modulo for negative numbers.

Comment: @EOF, True about _neg_ numbers.  In any case the `%` will be the remainder of the `/` and even with pre-C99, about code will generate a non-overflowed answer, but potentially a different answer should _neg_ values occur than against C99 or later code.

Comment: @chux Crucially, in pre-C99 code, `n%3` could be implementation-defined to always be positive, so the code could yield a *wrong value* for the mean if there were any negative numbers where `n%3 != 0`.

Comment: @EOF, Disagree.  With pre-C99, the `%` operator is still the _remainder_.  If the _remainder_ was always positive, the quotient would be 1 less when a negative `n` and `n%3 != 0`.  The final result would be `(a+b+c)/3`  with extended integer range.